# In Unix, WHILE command not reading file from a different directory

Tags: unix, while-loop

In Unix, WHILE command, I am trying to read a file, which is in another directory. But somehow not working, not even throwing any error.

```
while read line
do

echo $line 

done < /tmp/myfile.txt
```

The file is present in /tmp folder, has all the permissions.

Comment: **But somehow not working**? Please be precise when describing your problems.

Comment: The script is not returning any output. It is unable to read that file. In case I alter the file name to "/tmp/myfile.txtz" it is giving error that the file not found, which is fine. But it means earlier it was able to locate the file.

Comment: Works well for me.

Comment: Can you try putting below data in that file:

     case when status='EFF' then 1 when status='EXP' then 2 end

I think the issue is due to the single quotes present in myfile.txt. Does it make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear why your `while` loop is not working. Normally `loops`, `if` condition syntax are different for different shell. Hence at the beginning of a shell script file we always define the `shell` where exactly this script should run and that first line is start with a `#`. Now do the following and check that might help you.

> create a file $vi test.sh 
>   put the below line in it

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
filename="/tmp/myfile.txt"

while [ 1 ]
do 
    read -r line       
    if [ ${line:-1} -eq 1 ]; then
        break
    else
        echo $line
    fi
done < "$filename"
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
filename="/tmp/myfile.txt"

while read -r line
do
  echo $line
done < "$filename"
```

save the file and set the permission like below
    $chmod 777 test.sh

now run the file
    $./test.sh

Comment: Hi Abhijit,
I had included #!/usr/bin/ksh in my original script, still it was giving same error. 
Analyzed it more, got to know that the issue is caused due to the single quotes present in myfile.txt

case when status='EFF' then 1 when status='EXP' then 2

As an alternative i am using FOR loop, it is working fine.

Thanks buddy for the suggestion.